# Excel VBA functions generating #REF depending on function name?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2010, and have defined the following 3 functions in spreadsheet's Module.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function AAA() As Double

    AAA = 3
End Function

Public Function AAA2() As Double

    AAA2 = 4
End Function


Public Function AAA3AAA() As Double

    AAA3AAA = 5
End Function
```

When I reference the three functions in my spreadsheet by entering the following into 3 adjacent cells

```
=AAA()
=AAA2()
=AAA3AAA()
```

The second function generates a #REF error.  The other functions work as expected.  Anyone know why this is happening?  The reason I'm asking is a few of my macros quit working when I upgraded from Office XP to Office 2010.  After quite a bit of experimenting, it appears the function name itself is the culprit?  The error did not occur in Excel from Office-XP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same thing happened to me.  What I notice is that unlike the other two, "AAA2" could be the text of a **cell address**.  I suspect that's the problem.

Comment: That's it.  My exact function name was different than the example above... but it could have been interpreted as a cell address.

Comment: + 1 RBarryYoung :) @thatshowthe: And hence the need to name your functions/procedures/variables appropriately really matters :) see point 3 http://siddharthrout.wordpress.com/2011/08/01/to-err-is-human/

Comment: The function  name is an acronym, shortening from 24 characters to 4.  The name is meaningful, in the context I use it to those with domain knowledge.    My problem was I naively assumed that any valid identifier `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` was valid for a function name in VBA.